# How to set an angular mat panel expandable always expanded

Tags: angular, angular-material

is there any way to set an angular mat panel expandable always expanded?. I don't want to close it when user clic on the panel header

Thanks...

Answer (score 12):

```
<mat-expansion-panel [disabled]="true" [expanded]="true">
```

see https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api

Comment: `<mat-expansion-panel disabled expanded>` should work as well.

Answer (score 3):

Below code works for all scnerio, please check.

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngIf="currentCommittee" [expanded]="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

*ngIf helped me in my case where I needed to check for variable from service and if it is set to true then I will expand the panel:

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngIf="navigationService.varIsTrue || true"
                     [expanded]="navigationService.varIsTrue" 
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution:
`.mat-expansion-panel-header { pointer-events: none; }`

You will need to disable view encapsulation:
`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`